# Странное отображение строки в консоли (С)

Tags: c, строки

Код:

```
char* converted = ConvertDoubleToStr(666654);
printf("Converted string: %s \n", converted);
return 0;
```

Функция:

```
char* ConvertDoubleToStr(double d)
{
    printf("Input: %lf \n\n", d);
    const int length = sizeof (double);
    char result[length] = " ";

    sprintf(result, "%g", d);
    printf("Double -> Str. : %s \n", result);

    return result;
}
```

В самой функции **ConvertDoubleToStr** после конвертации в строку, отображение на консоль производится **правильно**. А при выходе из функции - отображаются крякозябры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?**

Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, вы возвращаете наружу указатель на локальный массив, который уничтожается при выходе из функции. Возвращенный указатель указывает в никуда. Потому и отображаются кракозябры.

Во-вторых, почему вы решили, что массив символов размером `sizeof(double)` достаточен для преобразования значения типа `double` в строковое представление? При чем здесь вообще  `sizeof(double)`?

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно заметил AnT, вы возвращаете из функции указатель на локальный массив, который уничтожится при выходе из этой функции. К тому же, вы неверно вычисляете длину результирующей строки. `sizeof(d)` вернет одно и то же значение, каким бы не было число `d`.

Основная сложность в решении задачи — это вычислить необходимую длину буфера. Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Она возвращает количество байт, которые *были бы* записаны в буфер, *если бы `n` не было бы равно нулю*. Если `n` равно 0, то первый аргумент функции (буфер) вообще игнорируется и в него [буфер] ничего не пишется, но количество записанных байт все равно вычисляется и возвращается — то что надо!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ConvertDoubleToStr(double d)
{
    /* Вычисляем длину числа d в символах. Если dLength < 0, то произошла
       ошибка — возвращаем NULL */
    int const dLength = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lf", d);
    if (dLength < 0)
        return NULL;

    /* Выделяем память для результирующей строки. Не забываем добавить 1 для
       нуль-терминатора. Если result == NULL, то произошла ошибка при выделении
       памяти — возвращаем NULL. */
    char *result = malloc(dLength + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Записываем d в стоку result. Если возвращаемое значение snprintf < 0,
       то произошла ошибка — освобождаем result и возвращаем NULL. */
    int const resultLength = snprintf(result, dLength + 1, "%lf", d);
    if (resultLength < 0) {
        free(result);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Осталось только вернуть буфер из функции. Освободить выделенную для
       буфера память должен вызывающий код. */
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *dStr = ConvertDoubleToStr(3.1415926535);
    puts(dStr);
    free(dStr);
}
```

Comment: Т.к. я использую С а не С++, мне пришлось  использовать функцию 'sprintf(resultT, "%lf", d);'  
и на выходе я получаю ошибку Access violation,  хотя из функции возвращается правильная строка

Comment: @LeonidZolotarov, код, что я привел в ответе — это код на C. Компилятор C++ даже не скомпилировал бы его. Функция `snprintf` — это функция стандартной библиотеки **языка C**. Я так понимаю, вы оба вызова `snprintf` заменили `sprintf`. Тогда не удивительно, что вы получаете *access violation*. Вы можете заменить `snprintf` на `sprintf`, но *только* во втором вызове!